How can you scope the registry in npm in a pom.xml file?
You can configure the package registry in npm multiple ways described here.
To configure in a pom.xml file, you can simply prefix any npm configuration property with npm_config_. So to configure the registry, you'd use this syntax:
<configuration>
  <npm_config_registry>https://registry.yarnpkg.org</npm_config_registry>
</configuration>

The equivalent means by which to configure the registry via the command line is this:
npm config set registry https://registry.yarnpkg.org

There is a way for the command line option to scope the registry configuration like this:
npm config set @mycompany:registry https://registry.yarnpkg.org

This will result in the https://registry.yarnpkg.org registry only being used for @mycompany packages.
There doesn't seem to be a pom.xml file equivalent for this.
The following is invalid XML:
<configuration>
  <npm_config_@mycompany:registry>https://registry.yarnpkg.org</npm_config_@mycompany:registry>
</configuration>

The following would set the registry and scope separately:
<configuration>
  <npm_config_registry>https://registry.yarnpkg.org</npm_config_registry>
  <npm_config_scope>@mycompany</npm_config_scope>
</configuration>

How can you scope the registry in npm in a pom.xml file?
